# Can I use SQLite for heavy use purpose?

Tags: windows, sqlite, variables, synchronization

Consider two application.

1. "A" application receives data from internet like player position and other details
2. "B" application which also needs the player position but it will be blocked from accessing internet. So the only way is to use SQLite sync player position (these frequently updates in milliseconds).

I can't even use socket or any other plugins too. So do you think SQLite can handle read and write in milliseconds without using CPU heavily ?

Comment: Are both apps on the same machine? Is app b read only? How large will the dataset be that needs to be synced?

Comment: @AsadAwadia Yes, both apps are in the same machine and app b is readable and writable. The dataset will be just two rows or you can consider as only two strings. But these strings will be changed each milliseconds. The dataset won't even get higher than 100kb.

Comment: Can app b write to the sqlite file? Or will it only be reading from it?

Comment: @AsadAwadia b can write and read sqlite file. Both A and B has full access to the SQlite file. But in my situation, I need both A and B to read and write data continuously.

Comment: How often will b write to sqlite?

Comment: @AsadAwadia Both A and B will write and read at the same rate to the database. 
A reads data created by B and B reads the data created by A

Comment: You will probably need an RDBMS that supports row-level locking for this. SQLite doesn't do that.

Comment: So both apps will do 1k writes per second?

Comment: Is this on ssd?

Comment: @AsadAwadia Yes both apps do 1k writes per second and it can be on SSD or HDD based on user choice.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield that's the problem here. I don't have access to any other things except file reading and SQLite database.

Comment: I just advice to use Redis in this case

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev As I mentioned I don't have any other permissions to add any other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to share the data in anything like real-time then I would use something like inter-process pipes or file mapping (memory) for this.

Writing data to and reading it back from any form of hardware storage will add quite a delay to the data passing, which will only become worse as the hardware data cache is filled.
Hardware is okay for historic data.

Both are supported by Win32 and should be accessible even if you use .NET to produce a UWP application.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication)